# ComboBox width in C# VS2017 WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, visual-studio-2017

Stupid mistake, this new machine has a strange resolution and I just couldn't see and grab the size control handles. Please ignore. Sorry to waste everybody's time.

....................

This has been driving me crazy for the past 20 minutes. I can't change a `ComboBox`'s width for my WinForms app. It's locked or something, when I type a new value in the properties it goes back to the original value.

To be a little more clear, I create a new solution, drag a combobox on the form, and the width is not changeable. Have comboboxes become unadjustable in the recent VS versions and I don't know about them?

Comment: Can you include the relevant designer file code?

Comment: Regarding to your deleted answer, you can delete the question.

Comment: Tried, it doesn't allow me: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit help center."

Answer (score 0):

> It's locked or something

It probably is. When you design the user interface (UI) of your Windows application, you can lock the controls once they are positioned correctly, so that you do not inadvertently move or resize them.

To unlock your combobox, change its `Locked` property to `false`.

You can find more details about the `Locked` property on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-lock-controls-to-windows-forms).

Comment: Nope, Locked is false